# Change Data Capture in delimited files

Tags: shell

There are two tab delimited files (file1, file2) with same number and structure of records but with different values for columns.

Daily we get another file (newfile) with same number and structure of records but with some changes in column values.

Compare this file (newfile) with two files (file1, file2) and update the records in them with changed records, keeping unchanged records intact.

Before applying changes:

```
file1 

11 aaaa 
22 bbbb 
33 cccc 

file2 
11 bbbb 
22 aaaa 
33 cccc 

newfile 
11 aaaa 
22 eeee 
33 ffff
```

After applying changes:

```
file1 
11 aaaa 
22 eeee 
33 ffff 

file2 
11 aaaa 
22 eeee 
33 ffff
```

What could be the easy and most efficient solution? Unix shell scripting? The files are huge containing millions of records, can a shell script be efficient solution in this case?

Comment: Example files might be extremely useful...

Comment: Are you updating a DB? If so which type (Oracle, etc)? The DB should be able to update records much faster than a shell script. Else, how are these files being used? Why can't you just use the newfile? Please update your question with your sample data. Use 4 spaces in front of each line and a blank line before and after so it will format correctly. ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : First the delimited files will be created then loaded to Oracle DB.

Comment: I don't see how making changes to an existing file based on a new file, when the result should be the same as the new file will be of value. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : I wanted to post an example but not able to add newlines. Tried adding two spaces at the end, but it's not working. Can someone guide me? Also, how can I preview message before posting? Sorry, for these basic questions.

Comment: Before applying changes:    


file1    

11 aaaa    

22 bbbb    

33 cccc    


file2    

11 bbbb    

22 aaaa    

33 cccc    


newfile    

11 aaaa    

22 eeee    

33 ffff    


After applying changes:    


file1    

11 aaaa    

22 eeee    

33 ffff    


file2    

11 aaaa    

22 eeee    

33 ffff

Comment: again I say, file1 = file2 = newfile. Just copy newfile to file1, and copy newfile to file2. Good luck. Else you should be doing this in the database.

Comment: @shellter : That makes sense. I realized it now. Thanks for pointing it. I sent an email to client asking if I misunderstood the requirements. sent the above example.

Comment: What might make a difference is if `file1` also contained a record `44 dddd` and `file2` also contained a record `55 eeee`.  If the incoming data contained `44 xxxx` and `55 yyyy`, then the entry in `file1` for `44` would be modified to `44 xxxx`, but there'd be no entry in it for `55`, whereas in `file2` the entry for `55` would be updated to `55 yyyy` but there'd be no entry in it for `44`.  However, this is speculation, but it would make some sense of applying an algorithm where the example does not make sense — a straight copy of the new file over each of the old files would do the job.

Comment: Number of records are same in all files.

Answer (score 0):

> Daily we get another file (newfile) with same number and structure of records but with
>   some changes in column values.

This sounds to me like a perfect case for [**git**](http://git-scm.com). With git you can commit the current file as it is.

Then as you get new "versions" of the file, you can simply replace the old version with the new one, and commit again. The best part is each time you make a commit git will record the changes from file to file, giving you access to the entire history of the file.

Comment: Can you please look at the example posted above. I am unable to format it to include line brakes, but all files have 3 records, 2 columns each. I can do this using shell script, but would like to know any other way as shell script might take too much time processing millions of rows. If git can do this efficiently, I will explore that option. Also, I think git would be useful as it maintains history as well. We currently don't require history, but maybe for some other projects.